# Reducing knapsack problem to an inverse knapsack problem

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, proof, np-complete, proof-of-correctness

1)Suppose we have a common 0-1 knapsack problem. Given a set of n items numbered from 1 up to n, each with a weight w_i and a value v_i, along with a maximum weight capacity W. Here we need to select some of the objects, so that maximize sum of v_i, such that sum of w_i of selected objects will not exceed the given W number.

```
       maximize∑(v_i*x_i), such that ∑(w_i*x_i)≤ W
```

2)Now suppose we have just the same problem, but we need to select objects so that  sum of their values will be minimal, and sum of their weights can't be less than the given number.

```
      minimize∑(v_i*x_i), such that ∑(w_i*x_i)≥ W.
```

Knowing that first problem is NP complete, how can I prove that second one has the same complexity, in other words is NP complete too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Knowing that first problem is NP complete, how can I prove that second one has the same complexity, in other words is NP complete too?

If you want to prove that problem `B` is NP-complete, you have to prove that there exists a polynomial time reduction from `A` to `B`, where `A` is known to be a NP-complete problem.
A polynomial-time reduction from a problem `A` to a problem `B` is an algorithm that solves problem `A` using a polynomial number of calls to a subroutine for problem `B`, and polynomial time outside of those subroutine calls.([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction)).

So in your case, your can easily make a polynomial time reduction from the knapsack problem to the inversed knapsack problem.
These two problems are equivalent (finding an optimal solution to one immediately solves the other).
Let `S` be the set of objects, `M` be the sum of the weights of the objects of `S`, and `W` the capacity of the knapsack.
Then, we have:

- `(i)` finding a subset of objects such that the sum of their weight does not exceed `W` and the sum of their value is maximal

is equivalent to

- `(ii)` finding a subset of objects such that the sum of their weight is of at least `M-W` and the sum of their value is minimal.

That is because if `S'` is an optimal solution of `(i)`, then `S\S'` is an optimal solution of `(ii)` (and vice-versa).

This is a polynomial time reduction (`O(1)` calls to the subroutine, polynomial number of operations), so the inversed knapsack is indeed NP-complete.

Comment: I see; the point of chosing `M-W` as the bound for the second formulation was missingin ConfusedSoul's answer. However, I believe my answer also to be correct.

Comment: Yes, the idea was right, it was just explained in a somewhat confusing way.  Also, seeing that the solution of the one is the complement of the solution to the other allows a clear visualization (choosing the objects we take is equivalent to choosing the objects we do not take).

Answer (score 0):

The key idea seems to be to exchange value and weight and use binary search on the second problem to construct the reduction.

Given an instance `I` of the first formulation with values `v_i` and weights `w_i`, construct an instance of the second problem by exchanging profits and weights. The sum of all weights (which now are the profits) is bounded by

```
n * w_max
```

where `w_max` is the maximum weight. This number itself is exponential in the encoding length of the input; however, we can use binary search to determine the maximum attainable profit such that the initial capacity `W` is not exceeded. This can be done in

```
log( n * w_max )
```

iterations, a number which is polynomially bounded in the encoding size of the input, using the same number of calls to an algorithm for the second problem. The described algorithm is the polynomial rediction from the first problem to the second problem.

Answer (score -2):

The inverse knapsack is one of my favorites. While I have never explicitly proven that it is NP complete, I do know how to reformulate the question to the knapsack problem itself, which should do the trick:

Rather than adding objects to an empty bag, consider the problem of choosing objects to be removed from a bag that is full. Then, since the number of weights can't be less than a given number, we must remove only up to total (weight-minimum weight) in terms of objects.

Since the price is to be minimized, then the price of objects to be removed must be maximized.

We are left with the initial knapsack problem, where we have to select a group of items (to be removed) such that we maximize their price, and their total weight does not exceed weight-minimum weight. (At the end, we take the items we did NOT remove as the solution)

We have reformed the problem to be exactly the original knapsack problem, therefore it must be NP-complete as well.

The beauty of this method is that I personally have no idea what NP complete it; I just proved that inverse knapsack and knapsack are perfectly equivalent.

Comment: I'm not quite convinced - how is it guaranteed that the remaining items fit into the knapsack, i.e. their weight does not exceed `W`?

Comment: their weights must be greater than W, as specified in the inverse no?